# Ошибка при подключении AJAX

Tags: ajax

Делаю веб-чат на php+ajax(для отправки сообщений без перезагрузки страницы).

Ошибка следующего вида:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Погуглил,говорят нужно добавить Async к скрипту,т.е. вот так будет:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" async></script>
```

После этого ругается на строчки

```
    google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");
    google.load("jqueryui", "1.7.2");
```

Ошибка такого вида:google is not defined

Что не так с подключением?

Код файла в котором возникает ошибка:

```
<!-- Стили для блока с сообщениями!-->
<style>
#messages
{
    width:300px;
    height:150px;
    overflow:auto;
    border:1px solid silver;
}
</style>

<!--Подключаем Jquery!-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" >
    //Загружаем библиотеку JQuery
    google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");
    google.load("jqueryui", "1.7.2");

    //Функция отправки сообщения
    function send()
    {
        //Считываем сообщение из поля ввода с id mess_to_add
        var mess=$("#mess_to_send").val();
        // Отсылаем паметры
       $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "add_mess.php",
                data:"mess="+mess,
                // Выводим то что вернул PHP
                success: function(html)
                {
                    //Если все успешно, загружаем сообщения
                    load_messes();
                    //Очищаем форму ввода сообщения
                    $("#mess_to_send").val('');
                }
        });
    }

    //Функция загрузки сообщений
    function load_messes()
    {
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url:  "load_messes.php",
                data: "req=ok",
                // Выводим то что вернул PHP
                success: function(html)
                {
                    //Очищаем форму ввода
                    $("#messages").empty();
                    //Выводим что вернул нам php
                    $("#messages").append(html);
                    //Прокручиваем блок вниз(если сообщений много)
                    $("#messages").scrollTop(90000);
                }
        });
    }
</script>

<table>
<tr>
<td>
<div id="messages">
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<form action="javascript:send();">
<input type="text" id="mess_to_send">
<input type="button" value="Отправить">
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<script>
//При загрузке страницы подгружаем сообщения
load_messes();
//Ставим цикл на каждые три секунды
setInterval(load_messes,3000);
</script>
```

Comment: ну правильно, должна быть ошибка, при вызове google поставьте setTimeout()

Comment: я так понимаю это просто отсрочит появление ошибки?

Comment: нет конечно)) используя мой пример ошибок не должно быть, если конечно у вас нет других "скрытых проблем" в коде. По всей вероятности у вас просто не успевает загузиться js

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать проверку до вызова, примерно так:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function googleInits()
    {
        if(typeof google != 'undefined')
        {
           // Ваш код или метод для старта логики...
        }
        else
        {

            setTimeout(googleInits, 50);
        }
    }

    googleInits();
</script>
```